# jvm crash after adding more cpu and ram during runtime

Tags: jvm, java-8, tomcat7, vmware

A production tomcat stopped responding after 8 hours of adding more cpu and ram during runtime. There is no traceable log in catalina.out.

java process was still running in the background. There is no load on the system during that time period. No sign of Out of memory.

apache-tomcat-7.0.55
tomcat-native-1.1.31
java version "1.8.0_66"
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

Could it be because of the cpu and ram upgrade? Thanks.

I saw a post about it for java 6. I am not sure it is related to my issue.

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6840239

Comment: did you check for heapdump and threaddump

Comment: i didn't have those during that time.

Comment: The CPU and memory change shouldn't have any effect.  Never the less I would look for a JVM crash report. Are you sure the virtual machine didn't reboot?

Comment: The vm wasn't rebooted. JVM didn't really crash and the java process was running before i restarted tomcat.